# Determinate if command exists is always false

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

MacOS has `zsh` as the default shell.

The code to check if a command exists:

```
if command -v omz
then
    echo "exists";
else
    echo "does not exists";
fi
```

Run it and it always comes back as **does not exist** (tested with installed/uninstalled).

However, if I type the following in a shell:

```
$ ./test.sh
does not exists

$ omz
[prints out help dialigue]

$ command -v omz
omz
```

I tried different ways of testing, always the same.

---

`omz` ships with Oh-my-zsh and I'm using it to determine if Oh-my-zsh is installed in my automation scripts. What would be the correct way to check this?

Comment: You need a shebang in your script to tell the OS which command to use to execute the script...

Comment: Without one, zsh will use `/bin/sh` to execute it, and that might have a different path that doesn't include the command you're trying.

Comment: What does `type omz` outputs? What is the output of `echo $PATH` in your shell, and from the script?

Comment: @Shawn did that also did output for $SHELL it comes back as /bin/zsh. I can switch to /bin/sh by exporting $SHELL but the results are the same.

Comment: @KamilCuk `omz is a shell function from ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/cli.zsh` and for `$PATH` its `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: `omz is a shell function` it is not an executable, so `command -v` fails. There is no question in your post. What is your question?

Comment: @KamilCuk makes sense. The question is how to successfully test that this function exists?

Comment: You are doing that. The function does not exist in your script, ergo you are successfully testing that the function does not exist.

Comment: In addition, `zsh` is the default *user* shell; `/bin/sh` (a version of `bash` 3.2) remains the default system shell.

Answer (score 3):

> Determinate if command exists is always false

> omz is a shell function

It's a shell function. Shell functions are not exported. As I read, it is not possible in ZSH to export a shell function.

`command` fails, because there is no such command.

> is always false

It is not always false. Create an executable named `omz` and put it in your `$PATH` - for sure, `command -v` will return success then.

Or alternatively, define `omz` function or source the file that provides `omz` definition, before checking for it's existence.

> The question is how to successfully test that this function exists?

You are doing that. The function does not exist in your script, ergo you are successfully testing that the function does not exist. The test work.

If you want to specifically test if it is a function, use match `type` output, like `case "$(type omz)" in *shell\ function*) echo it is; ;; *) echo it is not; ;; esac`.

Comment: `omz` ships with Oh-my-zsh and I'm using it to determine if Oh-my-zsh is installed in my automation scripts. What would be the correct way to check this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions || https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+check+if+och-my-zsh+is+installed || https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/how+to+check+if+oh+my+zsh+is+installed

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

`zsh`'s build-in `which` have not `-s`(silent) option, use `/usr/bin/which`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if /usr/bin/which -s $1
then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

Comment: `which` is not standard, it is an external utility, and some versions do not even set an exit status to reflect the existence of the searched command. Prefer the `command` built-in.

Comment: Since he said his environment is `Mac OS`, the answer is based on the assumption that there is never no `which`.

Comment: Same results—not exist.

Comment: @Чайка You don't really know what version of `which` will be used, even under a known OS. In this case it could be the one that comes with macOS , the one from MacPorts, Homebrew... Adding the full path and assuming it is the same old BSD one (2006) that comes with macOS may solve the issue but 1) it may not, 2) it makes your solution non-portable while better, portable, solutions exist.

Comment: @rock3t sorry build-in commnand not support this shellscript.